# calling overloaded function from derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two questions:
1. If base class and derived class has the same member function- compute() and if I create an object of derived class and call derived_obj.compute(), then which class's function is invoked?

2.Could you justify the output for this:

```
     #include<iostream.h> 
    #include<iostream.h> 
class Base
{
    int x, y, z; 
    public: 
    Base()
    {
        x = y = z = 0;
    }
    Base(int xx, int yy = 'A', int zz = 'B')
    {
        x = xx;
        y = x + yy;
        z = x + y;
    }
    void Display(void)
    {
        cout<< x << " " << y << " " << z << endl;
    }
};
class Derived : public Base
{
    int x, y; 
    public:
    Derived(int xx = 65, int yy = 66) : Base(xx, yy)
    {
        y = xx; 
        x = yy;
    }
    void Display(void)
    {
        cout<< x << " " << y << " ";
        Display(); 
    }
};
int main()
{
    Derived objD;
    objD.Display();
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Where is `compute()`  and `derived_obj` ??

Comment: On your main you create a Derived  object and you call Derived.Display member function .. there is no secret there.

Comment: And in the title of your answer "overloaded" should be changed to "override"

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is the derived class's function that is called because the object objD has been declared as such.